# Datasnap response doesn't convert to json

Tags: delphi

I am returning a string response in my DataSnap server.

```pascal
function TServerMethods1.GetImagem(PhotoPath: string): string;
var
  ...
begin
  ...
  Result := StrEnv.DataString;
end;
```

This successfully returns a response with my base64 string

```json
{"result":["Qk02...."]}
```

I need to get the content of the `result`, this is my base64 string `'Qk02...'`. I was trying to get the response as a `TJSONObject` and then use `TJSONObject.Get('result').Value` to get my base64 string.

I tried about three ways and couldn't convert this to `TJSONObject`, in all the attempts it returns me a blank string.

```pascal
ShowMessage(RESTResponse1.Content); // This shows the result
lJOImagem := RESTResponse1.JSONValue as TJSONObject;
ShowMessage(lJOImagem.ToString); // This shows a blank message
try
  ShowMessage(lJOImagem.GetValue('result').Value)); // This shows a blank message
finally
  lJOImagem.Free;
end;
```

How to get the content of the `result`?

Comment: In the JSON you showed, `result` is not a string, it is an array containing 1 string element. What do you have [`RESTResponse1.RootElement`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTResponse.RootElement) set to?  If blank, [`JSONValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTResponse.JSONValue) should return the entire `TJSONObject` like you expect, then `GetValue('result').Value` would return a `TJSONArray` for the array. If `RootElement` is `"result"`, `JSONValue` would return the actual `TJSONArray` (and then `as TJSONObject` would fail)

Comment: Note that `JSONValue` "*Returns the response content string that was **successfully parsed** as a JSON value. **Otherwise, it returns Nil*.**" That implies maybe the parsing of the `Content` as JSON is failing. Did you check to make sure that `lJOImagem` is not `nil`?

Comment: `RESTResponse1.RootElement` is blank. `lJOImagem` is not null and has a size of 1. It means it is being converted. Now I just need to get the value from `lJOImagem`. `lJOImagem.GetValue('result').Value` returns me blank and can not be converted to a TJSONArray.

Comment: I could get the `JSONObject` using `RESTResponse1.JSONValue as TJSONObject`. Then `JSONObject.Get('result')` returned me a TJSONArray as you told and a casted it. I looped through the array and the first `JSONValue` was already the value I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSONObject` was successfully being created. The problem was in the way I was accessing the value.

[image: JSONArray explanation]
The image was built by me.

The whole response is a `TJSONObject`, `JSONObject.GetValue('result')` is a `TJSONArray`. If I loop through the array It will loop only once and retrieve a `TJSONValue` which its value is the string I wanted `Qk02...`

The code is like that

```
vJSONObject := RESTResponse1.JSONValue as TJSONObject;
if vJSONObject <> nil then
begin
  vJSONArray := vJSONObject.GetValue('result') as TJSONArray;
  for vJSONValue in vJSONArray do
  begin
    memo.Text := vJSONValue.Value; // This is the string I wanted: Qk02..
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your string into a `JsonObject`. To do this, you have to convert your string into bytes and then convert it into a `JsonObject` as following :

```
var MyObject : TJSONObject;
MyObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(
TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RESTResponse1.Content), 0) as TJSONObject;
```

You don't have to use `TEncoding.ASCII`. You can also use `TEncoding.UTF8/Unicode/Etc` depending on your encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I upvoted your answer because it effectively converts the string response from `RESTResponse1.Content` to a `JSONObject`. Actually, it was the only answer I found that worked for a big string like a base64 photo. After some research, I found out that my problem was not to get the `JSONObject` but in accessing it correctly.

Comment: Note that `ParseJSONValue()` has an overload that takes a `string` as input, so to don't need to convert to bytes manually at all